# Finding a maximum sum contiguous sub array - another version

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, math, divide-and-conquer

There are a lot of posts in this forum for finding largest sum contiguous subarray. However, a small variation of this problem is, the sub array should at least have two elements.

For example, for the input `[-2, 3, 4, -5, 9, -13, 100, -101, 7]` the below code gives 100. But, with the above restriction, it will be 98 with sub array `[3, 4, -5, 9 , -13, 100]`. Can someone help me do this? I could not get a proper logic for this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int maxSubArraySum(int a[], int size)
{
   int max_so_far = 0, max_ending_here = 0;
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
     max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i];
     if(max_ending_here < 0)
        max_ending_here = 0;
     if(max_so_far < max_ending_here)
        max_so_far = max_ending_here;
    }
    return max_so_far;
} 

/*Driver program to test maxSubArraySum*/
int main()
{
   int a[] = {-2, 3, 4, -5, 9, -13, 100, -101, 7};
   int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
   int max_sum = maxSubArraySum(a, n);
   printf("Maximum contiguous sum is %d\n", max_sum);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

**Update 1:**
Made a change according to starrify but I do not get what I'm expecting. It gives 183 instead of 98.

```
#include<stdio.h>

const int size = 9;

int maxSubArraySum(int a[])
{
    int max_so_far = 0;
    int i;
    int max_ending_here[size];
    int sum_from_here[size];

    max_ending_here[0] = a[0];
    //sum_from_here[0] = a[0] + a[1];

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        max_ending_here[i] = max_ending_here[i-1] + a[i];
        sum_from_here[i] = a[i-1] + a[i];

        if (max_so_far < (max_ending_here[i] + sum_from_here[i]))
            max_so_far = max_ending_here[i] + sum_from_here[i];

    }

    return max_so_far;
}

/*Driver program to test maxSubArraySum*/
int main()
{
    int a[] = { -2, 3, 4, -5, 9, -13, 100, -101, 7 };
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    int max_sum = maxSubArraySum(a);
    printf("Maximum contiguous sum is %d\n", max_sum);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The approach:**

1. Let `max_ending_here` be an array, whose element `max_ending_here[i]` denotes the maximum sum of subarrays (could be empty) that ends just before (not included) index `i`. To calculate it, use the same approach as it in your function `maxSubArraySum`. The time complexity is `O(n)`, and space complexity is `O(n)`.
2. Let `sum_from_here` be an array, whose element `sum_from_here[i]` denotes the sum of a length-2 subarray starting from (included) index `i`, which means `sum_from_here[i] = a[i] + a[i + 1]`. The time complexity is `O(n)`, and space complexity is `O(n)`.
3. Iterate through all valid indices and find the maximum value of `max_ending_here[i] + sum_from_here[i]`: that value is what you are looking for. The time complexity is `O(n)`, and space complexity is `O(1)`.

Thus the overall time complexity is `O(n)` and the space complexity is `O(n)`.

This approach is extendable to arbitrary minimum length -- not only 2, and the time & space complexity do not grow.

Your original implement in `maxSubArraySum` is actually a special case of this approach above in which the minimum subarray length is 0.

**EDITED:**

According to the code you provide in update 1, I made a few changes and present a correct version here:

```
int maxSubArraySum(int a[])
{
    int max_so_far = 0;
    int i;
    int max_ending_here[size];
    int sum_from_here[size];

    max_ending_here[0] = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        max_ending_here[i] = max_ending_here[i - 1] + a[i - 1];
        if (max_ending_here[i] < 0)
            max_ending_here[i] = 0;
        sum_from_here[i] = a[i] + a[i + 1];

        if (max_so_far < (max_ending_here[i] + sum_from_here[i]))
            max_so_far = max_ending_here[i] + sum_from_here[i];

    }

    return max_so_far;
}
```

Notice the key is `max_ending_here[i]` and `sum_from_here[i]` shall not overlap. Here's an example:

```
-2   3   4   -5   9   -13   100   -101   7
   | 3   4   -5   9 | -13   100 |
           |              |
           |              |
          this            |
           is             |
    max_ending_here[5]    |
                          |
                         this
                          is
                    sum_from_here[5]
```

Comment: @Hem In the code you provide later, the array `max_ending_here` is calculated incorrectly: don't forget the `if (max_ending_here < 0) max_ending_here = 0;` check. Also at line 18 the calculation suggests `sum_from_here` overlaps with `max_ending_here`, which is also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using a sliding-window algorithm which I have implemented [here](http://ideone.com/dkhpa0).

At all points during the algorithm we maintain the following

1. A window [lo...hi].
2. The sum of the current window.
3. A variable called index that tracks the bad prefix in the current window removing which will increase the value of the sum. So if we remove the prefix [lo...index] then the new window becomes [index+1 ... hi] and the sum increases as [lo...index] had a negative sum.
4. The sum of the prefix stored in a variable prefixSum. It holds the sum for the interval [lo...index].
5. The bestSum found till now.

Initialize

- window =[0 ... 1]
- sum = arr[0] + arr[1](http://ideone.com/dkhpa0)
- index = 0
- prefixSum = arr[0]

Now during each iteration of the while loop,

- Check if a prefix exists in the current window removing which will increase the value of the sum
- add the next value in the list to the current interval and change the window and sum variables.
- Update bestSum variable.

The following **[working Java code](http://ideone.com/dkhpa0)** realizes the above explanation.

```
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = 1;
        int sum = arr[0] + arr[1];
        int index = 0;
        int prefixSum = arr[0];

        int bestSum = sum;
        int bestLo = 0;
        int bestHi = 1;

        while(true){
            // Removes bad prefixes that sum to a negative value. 
            while(true){
                if(hi-index <= 1){
                    break;
                }
                if(prefixSum<0){
                    sum -= prefixSum;
                    lo = index+1;
                    index++;
                    prefixSum = arr[index];
                    break;
                }else{
                    prefixSum += arr[++index];
                }
            }

            // Update the bestSum, bestLo and bestHi variables. 
            if(sum > bestSum){
                bestSum = sum;
                bestLo = lo;
                bestHi = hi;
            }

            if(hi==arr.length-1){
                break;
            }

            // Include arr[hi+1] in the current window. 
            sum += arr[++hi];
        }
        System.out.println("ANS : " + bestSum);
        System.out.println("Interval : " + bestLo + " to " + bestHi);
```

At all points during the algorithm *lo+1<=hi* and at each step of the while loop we increment *hi* by 1. Also neither the variable *lo* nor *index* ever decrease. Hence time complexity is linear in the size of the input.

Time complexity : `O(n)`

Space complexity : `O(1)`